# Meaning of zero article in headlines: "Man has serious injuries after being rescued"

Tags: zero-article, headlinese

> **Man** has serious injuries after being rescued from a "deep hole".

This is a headline in a newspaper and I am wondering why there is no article before "Man".

Why it is not  "A man"  as the sentence speaks about one and a specific man (although he is unknown to us yet) and not about "man" in general.

The sentence seems to me that it speaks about man in general or mankind because there is no article.

Thank you

Comment: This is an example of "headlinese".

Comment: Headline writer makes full sentences, gets fired

Comment: That is actually **quite long for a headline**, I would have expected "Man Suffers Injuries From Deep Hole" or "Man Rescued From Deep Hole" or "Injuries For Man In Deep Hole".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headlines are a special form of writing where **word count**, and therefore **page space**, is very important.  Often **minor words are omitted**.

[**How to write headlines**](http://www.copyblogger.com/how-to-write-headlines-that-work/)

and this one talks about how ambiguous headlines can be [here](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/jan/09/secrets-great-headline-writing)

> Violinist linked to JAL crash blossoms
>   Sir Vivian Fuchs at palace

You sense of using **Man** to mean **mankind** is correct for normal writing, but headline writing is a **different beast**

Answer (score 6):

This is a special style of newspaper headlines. Articles, auxiliary verbs and "be" are often left out to save space.

> Actor dies. (An actor has died.)

There's no generalization at all.

Comment: In your example it is not just omitting, the verb has different form also.

Comment: The question was about articles.